# Function in completion-block is never executed

Tags: swift, request, completion

I have the following situation:

Classes involved are

- *ViewController* (of type UIViewController)
- *RequestHandler*
- *DataRequest* (imports Alamofire for the request)

Step 1)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    requestHandler.getData(view: self) 
}
```

So here, my instance of the *RequestHandler* class is calling its *getData()*-function.

Step 2)

```
func getData(view: ViewController) {
    let dataRequest = DataRequest()
    dataRequest.getDataTree(handler: self) { response in
        view.saveData(dataTree: reponse)
    }
}
```

In this *getData* method inside my class *RequestHandler* i'm creating an instance of the desired Request-class. In this case an instance of the class *DataRequest*. This instance then class its function *getDataTree()* and handles the response over to my *ViewController* by invoking the *saveData()*-function.

Step 3)

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire

class DataRequest {
    func getDataTree(handler: RequestHandler, completion: @escaping ([String:[String:[String:[SomeStruct]]]]) -> ()) {

        let requestURL = constants.Url.dataURL

        Alamofire.request(requestURL, method: .post, encoding: URLEncoding.default)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
                completion(self.getServices(jsonData: JSON(data: response.data!)))
    })
}

    private func getServices(jsonData: JSON) -> [String:[String:[String:[SomeStruct]]]] {
        var serviceDict: [String:[String:[String:[SomeStruct]]]] = [:]
        for (k, subJson):(String, JSON) in jsonData {
            let key = k
            let dict: [String:[String:[SomeStruct]]] = getNames(jsonData: subJson)
            serviceDict[key] = dict
        }
        return serviceDict
    }
```

..followed by declaration of *getNames*-function etc until in the end, the SomeStruct objects in the array get parsed too.

So now that you got the background-information, my problem is the following:
By debugging I found out that the function *getDataTree* is called and executed, but the *getServices*-function never executes, despite being called in the completion-block.

I've only started as a programmer less than a year ago, so my experience is limited. I might aswell just make a really trivial mistake.

Thanks alot for your help already!

Comment: Are you sure your request is successful? There seems to be no error response handling in your Alamo request. 

Does your getServices return anything? If you print out serviceDict before the return is it returning anything at all?

Comment: Can you debug the value of `response.result.isSuccess` and `response.result.value` and check if your request is successful and you get a valid result value? debugging `response.error` can also help you know more about any request errors.